# SQL unexpected return

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, easyphp

So basically, I have a simple Database with only one table (it's a test DB).
The table has 4 columns:

- ID
- Name
- OralGrade
- WrittenGrade

What I'm trying to do is pretty simple (that's why i'm asking for your help): I want to get the **name** and **average** of the student whith the highest average.

What i tried:

```
SELECT nom, MAX(avg) 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT nom, (noteOrale + noteEcrit)/2 as avg 
        FROM etudiant 
        GROUP BY nom) AS Table;
```

After trying this query, it returned me the **name** and an **average** but the **average** doesn't correspond to the name.

Can someone give me pointers or explain what went wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`.  No subquery is necessary:

```
    SELECT nom, (noteOrale + noteEcrit)/2 as avg 
    FROM etudiant 
    ORDER BY avg DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

It would appear that no `GROUP BY` is needed either, because the values are all on one row.

If they are multiple rows, then you need `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I put your answer as the correct one as it is slightly simpler.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use `limit` for this:

```
SELECT nom, avg
FROM (
    SELECT nom, (noteOrale + noteEcrit)/2 as avg 
    FROM etudiant 
    GROUP BY nom
) t
ORDER BY avg DESC
LIMIT 1
```

`mysql` allows you to use aggregation without including all non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause -- so your query is just returning an arbitrary value for name.

Comment: Thank you, both answers work perfectly :) i'll mark @Gordon Linoff 's answer as the correct one as it is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that the value returned for `nom` is *indeterminate*. The `MAX()` aggregate is causing the query to collapse all of the rows, and picks out the the highest value of avg. That part is working.

But the value returned for `nom` is from *some* row in the collapsed group, not necessarily the row that has the highest value of `avg`. The query basically told MySQL to return a value of `nom` from *any* row in the group.

Other databases would throw an error with the query, with an error message along the lines of "non-aggregate in SELECT list not in GROUP BY".

A non-standard MySQL-specific extension allows the query to run. (It is possible to get MySQL to follow the standard more closely, like other database, if we include ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY in sql_mode. With the extension disabled, MySQL would behave like other databases, and return an error.)

That's the reason for the "unexpected" behavior you observe.

(This answers the question you asked... explaining what went wrong.)

Answer (score -1):

Just list the rows where the sum of the two fields is equal to the higest sum of the two fields in all the rows. You don't need to divide by two . That's just scaling.

```
Select * from table
Where noteOrale + noteEcrit =
   (Select Max(noteOrale + noteEcrit)
    From table)
```

if you also want the computed avg in the output, add it to the select clause.

```
Select nom, noteOrale, noteEcrit,
    (noteOrale + noteEcrit)/2 Avg
from table
Where noteOrale + noteEcrit =
   (Select Max(noteOrale + noteEcrit)
    From table)
```